# SSIS Standalone Installation

Tags: sql-server, ssis, license

In my organization we have several SQL Server 2016 Enterprise licenses in use.  None of them are running SSIS.  Since they are not in use, could I install just SSIS 2016 on a separate server and still be covered under the original enterprise license?

Comment: Licensing questions generally aren't handled here. Even if they were, you are missing a lot of details necessary for getting a correct answer. Try [this](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/12/ask-microsoft-sql-server-licensing-question/), instead.

Comment: A wise man once said 'You should only trust licensing advice from the vendor who would sue you for non-compliance'.  We usually don't answer licensing questions (as stated in previous comment), I'd recommend you reach out to your licensing representative, they are pros at answering all these sorts of questions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is licensing based.

Answer (score 1):

You can, but read this article on the implications of doing so.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/install-windows/install-integration-services

Comment: The server I would like to install it on is already running SQL Server 2008 R2 - Database and SSIS.  I wonder if that would work?

Comment: You can run different versions of SQL on the same server. However, you might run into issues with ports and might to make some additional configurations to get it to work the way you want. Why not just install SSIS on one of your existing 2016 servers? Are you trying to limit load on the servers where 2016 is all ready configured?